# How to rely on other middlewares in express?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

What is the best practice for relying on other middlewares in an express middleware? Let's say my middleware relies on having bodyParser before it executes. Is there a better way than telling my users explicitly in the readme to include and run my dependencies first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your middleware requires `body-parser` and it would insert that middleware into the middleware chain itself, it may become problematic when the user is already including `body-parser` in their app (in other words, `body-parser` would be included twice).

It may work (never tried), but it may also cause unintended side effects, which is why I would document the requirement for `body-parser` but have the user install it themselves. Your middleware can explicitly throw an exception when it sees that `req.body` isn't defined for a request.